# have a hover effect on key down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some code that if you press W on your keyboard a sound is played.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 87) {
    event.preventDefault();
    sound.currentTime = 0;
    sound.play()
  } else {
    return false;
  }
})
function playSound() {
  sound.currentTime = 0;
  sound.play()
}
```

```css
.whitebg {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  transition: 1.5s;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.whitebg:hover {
  background-color: #555555;
  transition: 0.4s;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="whitebg key" onclick="playSound()">click or press W to play</div>
```

As you can see, when you hover over the DIV it will transition to having a gray background and white text in 0.4seconds, and will transition back in 1.5 seconds.

I want the keypress of W will have the same result as the mouse hover.
Please answer with pure JavaScript, not jQuery or somthing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this can do the trick:
 1. When you press down W key, it will add a class to the element
 2. When you release W key, it will remove the class from the element
So something like this might do the trick:

```
    const bg = document.querySelector(".whitebg");
    document.body.addEventListener("keypress", (e)=>{
      // Key code 87 refers to W key
      if(e.keyCode == 87) {
         whitebg.classList.add("active");
      }
    })

   document.body.addEventListener("keyup", (e)=>{
   // Removes the class "active" as soon as you release the key.
   whitebg.classList.remove("active");
})
```

Hopefully this can do the trick, although there's probably a shorter way to achieve this without two event listeners.

Comment: The `e` is basically the same thing as passing in `event`, it listens for when an event has occurred, in this case listens to the KeyboardEvent and it shows bunch of different options. It can also listen for MouseEvents and log them, and perhaps some other events. And with the `e` in the code, we then log the e.keyCode to get the code thats associated with the button pressed, so we can do the if statement.

Comment: can it be modified to work woth id, as I have other elements with th whitebg class? also, it works one way: key down works fine, but key up does nothing

Comment: You mean you have multiple elements with the `whitebg` class, but want to change only the one where `W` is pressed? In that case just change the variable in my answer above to  be `document.querySelector("#idHere")` and so its adds/removes the active class only from that element. If I understood correctly :)

Comment: it doesnt work. also, when the keydown worked, I used this code:
https://jsfiddle.net/9k3nafe4/ (only js), css as in my example but hover and .active at the same time

Comment: Try it now, I updated it: https://jsfiddle.net/9k3nafe4/1/ It works as imagined (at least as I've imagined what you'd like to achieve). Be ware that if some element is missing / you cant get to it in this jsfiddle, it will stop the function.

Comment: it's very good, only 1 problem: you need to continue holding W for the whole time. I need it to even if you press W for 0.1s, the transition will be 0.4 in and then 1.5 out. also updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9k3nafe4/4/

Comment: Oh well yea, in that case you might need to add / remove two different classes, or use timeout like mentioned above.

Comment: what do you mean by add/remove 2 classes? because timeout is messing with other parts of my code...

Comment: Sorry, I had to leave the house earlier. So, this is the closest I've got to what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/9k3nafe4/6/ As far as my knowledge goes, I can't think of a way that will let you on key press (without holding the key) to animate something thats 0.4s while in the meantime if you release that key to simultaneously remove the animated thing. Best I could've do is shorten the `active` class animation to 0.1s so it almost looks like a hover effect, closest I've got. Hope this gets near to what you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, it's perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your CSS to apply that style to the element when it's hovered, *or* when it also has class `active`. Then in your keydown event, simply add that class to the button.

Per Ted's suggestion in the comments below, I've added a timer that will also remove the highlight after 500ms.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode !== 87) return;

  event.preventDefault();
  flashPlayButton(500);
});

function flashPlayButton(ms) {
  var playButton = document.getElementById("play");
  playButton.classList.add("active");
  setTimeout(function() { 
    playButton.classList.remove("active");
  }, ms);
}
```

```css
.whitebg {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  transition: 1.5s;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.whitebg:hover, .whitebg.active {
  background-color: #555555;
  transition: 0.4s;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="play" class="whitebg key" onclick="playSound()">click or press W to play</div>
```

Comment: A timeout to remove the active class would be a nice addition, per the OP's bit about " and will transition back in 1.5 seconds."

Comment: @Ted The "transition back in 1.5 seconds" was referring to the time of completion from fade start to fade end, not necessarily the time it remains "Active" - that portion is already covered by OP's CSS. I've added a setTimeout nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a css class called blackbg to the div when W is pressed and then remove it when W is not pressed anymore.

```js
var whiteBg = document.querySelector('.whitebg');
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 87) {
    event.preventDefault();
    whiteBg.classList.add("blackbg");
    sound.currentTime = 0;
    soundE.play()
  } else {
    return false;
  }
})

function playSound() {
  sound.currentTime = 0;
  sound.play()
}

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 87) {
    event.preventDefault();
    whiteBg.classList.remove("blackbg");
  }
});
```

```css
.whitebg {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  transition: 1.5s;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.blackbg,
.whitebg:hover {
  background-color: #555555;
  transition: 0.4s;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="whitebg key" onclick="playSound()">click or press W to play</div>
```